# Datatype integer?

Tags: php, types, int

This is driving me crazy. For some **weird** reason, pdo's `fetch style` parameter's datatype is `integer`? It can't be integer, its more like a string without quotes around it.. Plus there is no numbers in it. I found it, when i was trying to make pdo function library, but it's not so important to this. Check this out:

```
echo gettype(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns 'integer'
```

What is this all about??

Comment: I think you have an error in your query and you get `false` or 0. Can you show us your query before?

Comment: No, the question is not about queries, its about fetch styles datatype.

Comment: The documentation states it's an integer (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php), PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is a flag. See http://3v4l.org/i6SFv for PDO constants and their values.

Comment: Why downwote please explain that unfriendly behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have edit your Question this is not a problem. `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is a constant in the PDO Class.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Here you can see all constants and you can see that the `PDO:FETCH_ASSOC` is an integer. This is only that you can use a defined value.

Comment: Yes but how this can be integer? Should it be something like flag or function parameter by its datatype?

Comment: @aksu Do you know what constants are? What's wrong with it being an integer?

Comment: @asku i don't see the problem look into the PDO Class there you can see all the constants that are defined in the class on top. You could write the integer value in the function but in most cases you don't know that 2 is for fetch assoc for example

Comment: Okayy!! So the pdo converts it to integer to match fetch style! clever!

Answer (score 2):

As per the PHP docs the `fetch_style` parameter is of type int, 
As per PHP docs

```
  fetch_style Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be
 one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE 
(which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH)
```

where PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is a constant whose value is 2. And the `gettype` function returns the type of variable.